# Show product of projective spaces minus a hypersurface is affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, affine-varieties

Let
$L=\{([a_{0}:a_{1}:....:a_{n}],[b_{0}:b_{1}:...:b_{n}]) \in P^{n}* P^{n}: \sum_{i}a_{i}b_{i}=0\}$

Show $P^{n}*P^{n}-L$ is affine.

I don't know where to start. I only know that if we use a Veronese mapping we can show that a projective space $P_{n}$ minus a hyperplane is affine.

Comment: Have you encountered the Segre embedding?

Comment: yes I have but how to use it? Like the segre embedding will correspond to coordinates such we would get zeros, $z_{ij}z_{kl}-z_{il}z_{kj}=0$ where the z's are the co-ordinates from the segre embedding. How can I use it to show it is affine? I only know that using this embedding product of projective spaces is a projective variety.

Comment: Can it be shown or could it be correct to say that if the product of projective spaces is a projective variety then taking out a hyperplane from the image of the embedding as complement would result in it being affine and that this hyperplane would be L? I am not very sure.

Comment: Same question was asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4827197/mathbbpn-times-mathbbpn-setminus-gamma-is-isomorphic-to-an-affin

Answer (score -2):

**Question:** "Show $P^{n}*P^{n}-L$ is affine.

I don't know where to start. I only know that if we use a Veronese mapping we can show that a projective space $P_{n}$ minus a hyperplane is affine."

**Answer:** Let us consider the case $n=1$ and the embedding

$$v: S:=\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow  \mathbb{P}^3:=X $$

(defined "pointwise" in the language of Hartshornes book CHI):

$$v((a_0:a_1)(b_0:b_1)):=(a_0b_0: a_0b_1:a_1b_0:a_1b_1).$$

Let $X:=\mathbb{P}^3$ have homogeneous coordinates $z_0,..,z_3$. In the embedding $v$ it follows the subvariety $Z \subseteq S$ defined by the equation $\sum a_ib_i=0$ is defined by the hyperplane $H:=V(l)$ where

$$l:=z_0+z_1+z_2+z_3.$$

It follows $H\cong \mathbb{P}^2$ and $X-H \cong \mathbb{A}^2$. Moreover $S-Z \cong S \cap \mathbb{A}^2 \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2$ is a closed subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^2$.
It follows $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1-Z$ is an affine variety.